# What does it mean if a hard disk is meant for NAS use?

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I plan to install a new hard disk in my desktop PC, and have been looking at Western Digital's Green and Red series. The Red are targeted at NASs, but what does this mean? Do they have a longer endurance, for instance, like more Power-On-Hours? Can I use this kind of drive in my desktop PC?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a WD Red HDD in your PC, but you might find the WD Blue or WD Black more suitable for your needs.

Choosing the best HDD for your needs depends a lot on the kind of usage you have – do you game a lot? Or do you use the PC mostly for browsing and document editing?

In general any HDD will work, but there are so many types of HDDs for a reason – different HDDs are optimized for different usage scenarios. The WD Red is dedicated for use in NAS or RAID systems since it's designed work 24/7 and also has vibration protection technology to help it cope with the excessive vibrations in multi HDD systems. It's also tuned for a lower power consumption since it's designed to be spinning 24/7. This is a great feature to have in a NAS system but if you are more interested in getting the best performance you might find a 7200 RPM HDD with dual processor like the WD Black better fitted for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are meant when a Hard-disk is described as for NAS or RAID environments. It is ordinarily because they'll have slightly modified/optimised firmware and some small enhancements within the way the product is physically constructed - usually to reduce running temperature etc

[This is actually confirmed by the documents on the WD Red page](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=810)

The green WD is for optimal power usage and unless you plan on doing crazy things with your home desktop I would use the green, purely as they're supposed to use less power and would be less heavy on your PSU and you will likely not be using the red WD optimally.

Hope this helps!